# show/hide html content in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have response which is coming from backend . Now i want to create some links, if i click those links it should display html content below that link and if i click that link again those html content should go. I know jquery hide() and show() . But here i am using for loop and i am not able to find DOM element ,
as follows,

```
var html = "<div id=finalDiv></div>";
$("#finalDiv").dialog();
var ht;
for(var i in response) {
  ht +="<table><tr><td><label>A:</label></td><td><a onclick=\"showOneLink('"+response[i].B+"','"+i+"')\" >'"+response[i].A+"'</a></td></tr>";
  ht += "<tr><td><div id=show'"+i+"'Link style='dislay:none;'></div></td></tr></table>";
}
$("#finalDiv").append(ht);
```

Now when i click showOneLink , hidden div should display but that div's DOM will not be created . As ,

```
function showOneLink(B,i) {
  var htm = "<b>log:'"+B+"'</b>";
  $("#show"+i+"Link").css('display','block');
  $("#show"+i+"Link").append(htm);
}
```

Comment: Please debug your code.
There are multiple unterminated strings in your last codeblock: (`"#show"+i+"Link`)

Comment: no that is not the problem . I corrected it

Comment: Ah yes, I see. The `.toggle();` suggestions posted below should work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this id attribute:

```
id=show'"+i+"'Link
```

That will produce invalid HTML:  `id=show'5'Link`

Change it to:

```
ht += "<tr><td><div id='show"+i+"Link' style='dislay:none;'></div></td></tr></table>";
```

Also use `toggle()` instead of `css()`:

```
 $("#show"+i+"Link").toggle();
```

Comment: no .. that is not the mistake here .. that i corrected it ..But i want answer for my question ..how to toggle without dom object inside for loop?

Comment: It is the problem. You can't find the DOM element because it has an invalid ID.

Comment: @SSS, if you corrected it then you should update your question with the new code.

Comment: @SSS, I agree with MrCode that you should change the id when you create the element : you have an invalid ID.

Answer (score 0):

Selectors are Strings, close the ""

like `$("#show"+i+"Link");`

or the hole code:

```
function showOneLink(B,i) {
  var htm = "<b>log:'"+B+"'</b>";
  $("#show"+i+"Link").css('display','block');
  $("#show"+i+"Link").append(ht);
}
```

and better use toggle:

```
    $("#show"+i+"Link").append(ht);
    $("#show"+i+"Link").toggle();
```